# How to generate LLVM bitcode

Tags: c++, llvm, bitcode

I want to generate bitcode file (.bc) as it is written in [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#example-with-clang):

hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

then

```
% clang -O3 -emit-llvm hello.c -c -o hello.bc
```

and

```
% lli hello.bc
```

to run the code, but I have weird output:

```
lli: Attributes.cpp:367: static llvm::AttrListPtr llvm::AttrListPtr::get(llvm::LLVMContext &, ArrayRef<llvm::AttributeWithIndex>): Assertion `Attrs[i].Attrs.hasAttributes() && "Pointless attribute!"' failed.
0  lli             0x0000000000c944ff
1  lli             0x0000000000c94a79
2  libpthread.so.0 0x00007fbf12a88060
3  libc.so.6       0x00007fbf11d663e5 gsignal + 53
4  libc.so.6       0x00007fbf11d69b4b abort + 379
5  libc.so.6       0x00007fbf11d5ed8d __assert_fail + 221
6  lli             0x0000000000b8b285 llvm::AttrListPtr::get(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::AttributeWithIndex>) + 517
7  lli             0x000000000051f14e llvm::BitcodeReader::ParseAttributeBlock() + 494
8  lli             0x00000000005249f1 llvm::BitcodeReader::ParseModule(bool) + 497
9  lli             0x0000000000526617 llvm::BitcodeReader::ParseBitcodeInto(llvm::Module*) + 359
10 lli             0x000000000052eae9 llvm::getLazyBitcodeModule(llvm::MemoryBuffer*, llvm::LLVMContext&, std::string*) + 569
11 lli             0x000000000052ee3f llvm::ParseBitcodeFile(llvm::MemoryBuffer*, llvm::LLVMContext&, std::string*) + 15
12 lli             0x00000000004ea29a llvm::ParseIR(llvm::MemoryBuffer*, llvm::SMDiagnostic&, llvm::LLVMContext&) + 170
13 lli             0x00000000004e7078 llvm::ParseIRFile(std::string const&, llvm::SMDiagnostic&, llvm::LLVMContext&) + 536
14 lli             0x00000000004e3a58 main + 312
15 libc.so.6       0x00007fbf11d5130d __libc_start_main + 237
16 lli             0x00000000004e1f49
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: lli hello.bc 
Aborted
```

What is the problem. Why it does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is likely a problem with your particular LLVM/Clang version. Have you compiled it from source with assertions enabled? You just need to get a newer build with that bug fixed. (See http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15786 for a similar assertion failure report with older version.)

FWIW - that program works fine on my local SVN build (clang version 3.4 (trunk 182672)).