# How to generate llvm bitcode for whole program analysis of open source projects? How to do it with llvm-link/gold plugin?

Tags: llvm

We can find solutions in the llvm documentation page itself, in here, https://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html. What is the significance, or how to choose of using llvm-link and llvm gold plugin? How can we generate whole-program bitcode (LLVM IR) of open source projects in C/C++ (SPEC 2000)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Haritha!. You can use clang to generate bitcode from clang supported source files(including C/C++), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782184/how-to-generate-llvm-bitcode.

Comment: Search for `wllvm`/`gllvm`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. But could anyone please give me some insights about what is the use of LLVM gold plugin and llvm-link?